# Linking CSS File To JSP

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I have a css file in my WEB-INF folder and in a jsp page i have given the location of the css file as  :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/Tabs.css"
```

But the problem is it doesn't link with the css file. If i take out the css file from the WEB-INF, it works perfectly.

This is my first time working with css.

What seems to be the problem here ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The WEB-INF directory is not public. Your css file must be out this directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is just as you describe it, the location of the css-file.
All resources located within the `WEB-INF-folder` is not reachable directly from the web browser, but has to be accessed through a servlet.

And this is the reason of why the css isn't loaded when you are visiting your jsp.

Try instead to put them in a more common structure such as `/webapp/resources/css/Tabs.css` and change the href to `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webapp/resources/css/Tabs.css`

**Edit **

The folder I refer to as webapp might have any name, but the location of it would be the parent folder of the WEB-INF folder.