# use css files with jsp

Tags: css, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am developing an application using spring mvc.
I created the html and css pages independently, and tested the application using simple blank jsp files.
So when I wanted now to integrate my html pages, I figured out that the css are not working.

calling the css file from the jsp:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "are not working" Mean?  Is that `<link/>` what's in your generated HTML?

Comment: Someone has already answered this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143750/linking-css-file-to-jsp?rq=1

Comment: You just have to get the relative location right. Try `href="./css/style.css"` for instance.

Comment: I already tried the solution and it's not working. and using  href="./css/style.css"   doesn't work neither. I still get html without styling

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring mvc ,then you should have below line in your spring configuration file.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

mapping && path  may be relative path of your static resources.

and inside the JSP file use below to access the css.

```
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I tried it and I'm getting the error: attribute for %>" is not properly terminated

Comment: Try this   <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: I have the resources folder in the WebContent folder. Is that a problem ?

Comment: can you tell me what exactly is the path of your css starting from the war file directory(in your file)?? Like for me it is -->  i have Root.war and my css file path is like Root--> resources --> css --> style.css

Comment: I don't know what a war file is! is it something related to maven or something like that ? because I'm not using maven

Comment: How are you deploying your web app in server? Can you tell me what is the location of css file in your development env, like for me  it like below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66821/discussion-between-re350-and-ben03).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```